# How to add a layer to Wikitude Browser?

Tags: android, wikitude

I'm trying to add a layer on top of the camera view of wikitude, to show images and text (to indicate POIs out of the user's vision to left and right). I couldn't find a tutorial showing how to add a extra layer to Wikitude, someone knows one?

Thanks,
Tere

Comment: Did you find anything useful do to this? I am having the same problem

Comment: After days investigating, I realized that Wikitude only provides Intents, and the code is not available (because it's an application and not a framework or open code). So I discarded Wikitude for my app. I moved then to Look AR (www.lookar.com), which is an AR framework that has a hud layer incorporated and easy to use but is not finished (I had to add many methods to the framework classes to do what I needed).

Comment: Thanks, but the link should be http://www.lookar.net

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't know if it's going to be fully relevant but they released ARChitect, a javascript library allowing to design worlds, as they call them, with HTML, javascript and css.

http://www.wikitude.com/developer/architect

You can choose what you display, and it seems pretty flexible. What I haven't found out yet is if it is possible to use this with in a custom view created with their Intents.

Good luck!